# OPLOG fully synced in two shared same mongodb projects when it's not pub/sub or collection declared

Tags: mongodb, meteor

### Condition

There are customer server and admin server.

The two server shares same mongodb and same database,
but the projects are separating Meteor project.

When the admin server insert a bulk data (over 70million) into 'A collection',
the customer server's cpu/memory runs extremely high during the admin server inserting the data.

So I could assume that the customer server fetching the inserted oplog data by admin server.

### Question

The point that I don't understand is,
why the customer server is forking or syncing the oplog data,
even there's no 'A collection' declair in customer server.
I expected that the customer server never fetching anything when the admin server insert a data, because 'It is not decliared in the customer server'.

So I want to know Meteor project is syncing oplog even the project has not declaired the collection on the same database.
Or is there other reason for this?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Oops- okay I will fix to be clear.

Comment: I've just updated question to be clear. Please try again-. Thanks to let me know @D.SM

Comment: There is still no question in your question.

Comment: Emm. The question is last sentence. "I want to know Meteor project is syncing oplog even the project has not declair the collection. Or is there other reason for this." I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: Do you understand Meteor & Reactive system by Oplog? @D.SM

Comment: I suppose that is technically a question but I do not understand what you are saying due to grammar.

Comment: I've updated to be clear more but it is also story about Meteor Reactive still. I believe someone could understand despite of my dummy poor english question ;)

Comment: You should be isolating where the problem is, not trying to expand it to include your entire stack. If you think the issue is with the database, remove as much of client side as possible and provide a reproduce case that uses only the driver and basic operations. Ideally mongo shell.

Comment: I don't understand your deployment architecture either. A two-node replica set?

Comment: The MongoDB architecture is Single-replica set. And tow projects are sharing the same exactly database and oplog.

Comment: You cannot have multiple processes using the same data directory.

Comment: I think you are fully specialized on MongoDB and I just attached 'MongoDB' tag because this kind of question is never fully separated with MongoDB in Meteor World. And even I couldn't be sure which side is problem in this case, Meteor or MongoDB. So if you can't fully understand then you could pass this one- ;)

Comment: Share database and make a reactive is a basic philosophy in Meteor, and it worked by oplog-

Answer (score 1):

[Self Solved]

I got appropriate answer on [Meteor forum](https://forums.meteor.com/t/cpu-memory-high-when-shared-mongodb-bulk-data-inserted-not-pub-sub-collection/54596/2?u=kakadais).

Shortly,
it is normal reaction in shared database model because two projects exactly shares their oplog fully.

So to avoid it, use redis-oplog-package to control 'write oplog' when instering.